# ODATA One value within a list or Select inside of a $filter?

Tags: filter, odata, querying

I have an OData query that has recently been updated to include paging and that has caused some of the filtering to be off.

the main object is brought back and it has a collection of child objects off of it. The child objects can be of two types; SOURCE or DESTINATION and each has a LocationID. I now need to expand the filter before the paging is performed to check if any of the Destinations has the same location as the single source. The single source and the multiple destinations are all contained in the same collection (table)

This is as far as I got when I got stuck on the $filter

```
(ChildItem/any(o: o/LocationID eq 9 and o/SOURCE eq 1))
```

I tried

```
(ChildItem/any(o: o/LocationID eq (ChildItem/any(o1: o1/LocationID)) and o/SOURCE eq 1))
```

But of course that is not a select statement. Is there anyway to do a select inside of a filter. I've never had to face this one before so any help would be appreciated. I did search other questions over the weekend and got nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following filter?

```
$filter=ChildItem/Namespace.Source/any(o: ChildItem/Namespace.DESTINATION/any(o1: o/LocationID eq o1/LocationID))
```

But such complex filter needs support from the server implementation.